# For what does `?` exist in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, types, nullable

Have read some documentation in MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

When I have seen the overview section I was wondering, what does that mean?

[image]

In C# there is a nullable data type:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

With the similar syntax to JS sample, which is in the screenshot from docs:

```
int? num = null;
```

It means, that a value types, which are struct like `int` can hold not just some value, but could a `null` value could be assigned to it.

But! JavaScript has a duck-typing and it is also a dynamic language with the weak typification. In JS I can assign null or undefined  to any value or even not set anything, it isn't a strict language as C#.

So... It can't be a nullable type as in C#, so what is it?

Comment: Note the word "optional". That's what the question mark is referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a interface definition, is not actual javascript code. It only means that that value can be `null`. It means exactly the same as in C#

Take into account that in javascript you don't declare the return value, and there you are seeing it.

Comment: If it's not Javascript, then what language is it?

Comment: I suppose that it's not the same as in C#. Nullable types in C# is rather more complex concept, than just a setter either to exact value or null. But as a help about MDN docs correct understanding - thanks!

Comment: None I know of. Think of it as an Interface Description Language, used to describe an interface without being language-specific. Think that the DOM may be accessed from javascript, C++, java, .NET. A javascript definition would not include the return type for a method, which is needed for the other languages.